# How to prevent cursive CSS fonts from extending beyond container border

Tags: html, css, fonts

Using the Google font [Mr De Haviland](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Mr+De+Haviland), I've noticed that the letters of this font overlap, especially the capital letters.  One glyph extends into the next. I'm sure this is intentional, as it create a nice cursive writing effect.

However this also makes parts of the letters extend past the barrier of a div or table cell. How can I make the container contain the entire letter, so they do not extend beyond the div into the margin, or get cut-off.  [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMoUD.png)

Adding padding is not the answer I'm looking for, because the amount of padding needed appears to vary depending on the letter.

Comment: Upon further research, this behavior is apparently called font kerning, and there is a CSS3 property "font-kerning: none" to prevent it, *IF* the font supplies kerning information.  See http://caniuse.com/#feat=font-kerning

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a small amount of `padding-left` and `padding-right` to all text containers that use this font, like

```
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  padding: 0 0.2em;
}
```

(Adjust that value to whatever really fits by trying different values in the browser tools)